# Is there a PHP equivalent to Python's __name__ == __main__?

Tags: php, class, oop, initialization

I want to be able to write a script with all functionality encapsulated within a class and be able to also use the file as a script if invoked directly. Python offers this with the `if __name__ == __main__` construct.

I searched the PHP docs for similar built-in variables and stackoverflow for previous mentions, but all corners came up empty. Posting this question on the off chance someone might know a way.

Does PHP have an equivalent?

Comment: I think you mean `if __name__ == "__main__":` in Python.

Comment: @Robert. Yes.  Updated for syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quick-and-dirty method:

```
if ($argv[0] != ""){
   echo ("Started from the command line");
}
```

Explanation:  if the file is started from the command line, then  `argv[0]` is the filename itself, therefore not an empty string.

When inserted with `require(filename)` then `argv[0]` is an empty string.

Comment: Interesting.  I will take it as there does not seem to be another method. Thanks for the hack!